# how to make Url from Pulled rest api data

Tags: javascript, json, api, url, hyperlink

I am trying to make a link/url from data that i'm pulling from a rest api. I can't find anywhere else that answers this problem. I currently pull the data from a rest api, then it is made into a constant, that constant needs to be turned into a clickable link. If more info is needed, let me know and i'll try to provide as much info as I can.

```
const artifactId = props.data.artifactId;
const group = props.data.group;

var jenkinsLink = 
(`${BASE_LINK_URL}${group}${BASE_LINK_URL_EXTENDED}
${artifactId}${BASE_LINK_URL_END}`);
```

currently the way im trying to turn it into a link is like so,

```
jenkinsLink= jenkinsLink.replace(/\s/g, "_");
```

[image]

where it says Java 7, that is supposed to be a link to the Jenkins page.

Comment: show us the data returned from the API

Comment: @SujitAgarwal I edited the main post.

Comment: is the link to be created a normal html anchor link or something specific to jenkins?

Comment: @SujitAgarwal   specific to jenkins.

Comment: I'm not too sure about jenkins due to lack of experience with it, I'll check and see.

Comment: @SujitAgarwal thank you for looking into it, i appreciate it.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the page where you're trying to integrate this code?

Comment: @SujitAgarwal added the image

Comment: Added a probable answer, please try and let me know the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the 'Java 7' text is having an ID 'javalink'
Now you can do this in your javascript code -

```
const artifactId = props.data.artifactId;
const group = props.data.group;

var jenkinsLink = BASE_LINK_URL + '/' + group + '/' + BASE_LINK_URL_EXTENDED  + '/' + artifactId + '/' + BASE_LINK_URL_END;

var obj = document.getElementById('javalink');
obj.innerHtml = jenkinsLink;
```

Comment: i'm getting a problem saying cannot return href property of null.

Comment: can you inspect the section where 'java 7' is written and see what ID or class it is assigned? this can make things easier

Comment: <div href=" {`${jenkinsLink}${JAVA_7}`}">      Java 7</div>                                                 this is what it is saying before I add your changes